# Use time interval to calculate mean from another data frame

Tags: r, datetime, mean

I have two data frames. One data frame contains the the time of a net set (beginning) and lift (end). I need to use this time period to calculate the mean DO from my second data frame. I am having issues matching the times because the times in the catch data frame are specific, whereas the times in the DO data frame are hourly. I tried matching to the closest time but couldn't manage that, so my next thought was to just use anything within the time interval. The mean needs to be specific to a boat and net within the time interval. I am doing this for several very large data sets so I need to be able to loop the function rather than code for each line.

catchdf:

```
Boat    Net   Set                    Lift
Dawn    26    2016-05-19 12:20:11    2016-05-27 11:48:36
Nip     26    2016-07-28 07:25:47    2016-08-07 06:13:10
Dawn    26.3  2016-08-01 13:24:51    2016-08-03 07:48:52
```

dodf:

```
time                   DO      Boat    Net
2016-05-19 13:00:00    10.2    Dawn    26
2016-05-21 15:00:00    10.4    Dawn    26
2016-05-26 09:00:00    10.9    Dawn    26
2016-05-28 10:00:00    9.4     Dawn    26
2016-07-28 09:00:00    11.9    Nip     26
2016-07-28 19:00:00    12.4    Nip     26
2016-08-04 04:00:00    5.4     Nip     26
2016-08-01 05:00:00    13.2    Dawn    26.3
2016-08-02 16:00:00    12.3    Dawn    26.3
2016-08-05 22:00:00    2.4     Dawn    26.3
```

My goal is to insert a column into the catchdf with the meanDO for each time period.

```
Boat    Net   Set                    Lift                  MeanDO
Dawn    26    2016-05-19 12:20:11    2016-05-27 11:48:36   10.50
Nip     26    2016-07-28 07:25:47    2016-08-07 06:13:10   9.90
Dawn    26.3  2016-08-01 13:24:51    2016-08-03 07:48:52   12.3
```

This is the code I used to make the sample data frames:

```
catchdf <- structure(list(Boat = c("Dawn", "Nip", "Dawn"), Net = c("26", "26", "26.3"), Set = c("2016-05-19 12:20:11", "2016-07-28 07:25:47", "2016-08-01 13:24:51"), Lift = c("2016-05-27 11:48:36", "2016-08-07 06:13:10", "2016-08-03 07:48:52")), .Names = c("Boat", "Net", "Set", "Lift"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

dodf <- structure(list(time = c("2016-05-19 13:00:00", "2016-05-21 15:00:00", "2016-05-26 09:00:00", "2016-05-28 10:00:00", "2016-07-28 09:00:00", "2016-07-28 19:00:00", "2016-08-04 04:00:00", "2016-08-01 05:00:00", "2016-08-02 16:00:00", "2016-08-05 22:00:00"), DO = c("10.2", "10.4", "10.9", "9.4", "11.9", "12.4", "5.4", "13.2", "12.3", "2.4"), Boat = c("Dawn", "Dawn", "Dawn", "Dawn", "Nip", "Nip", "Nip", "Dawn", "Dawn", "Dawn"), Net = c("26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26.3", "26.3", "26.3")), .Names = c("time", "DO", "Boat", "Net"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I've been stuck on this one for quite a while and haven't been able to make any progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I have edited it.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I tried matching to the closest time but couldn't manage that*"? It is easy to achieve to I would guess. Can you also add the desired output for the closest match? I mean you want a match for each `time` value or for each `Set` or `Lift` or some combination?

Comment: So my original idea was to match the set and lift to the closest time in the dodf, then take the mean of all the DO values between those two time periods. I think the approach you detailed where you use time > Set, time < Lift is more appropriate. I was basically trying to approach the problem a couple of different ways and see which one panned out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible data.table solution. First, we will fix the formats of your columns

```
library(data.table) #v1.10.4
cols <- c("Set", "Lift")
setDT(catchdf)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct), .SDcols = cols]
setDT(dodf)[, `:=`(time = as.POSIXct(time), DO = as.numeric(DO))]
```

Then we can make a non-equi join between the to data sets while calculating the mean on the fly

```
dodf[catchdf, .(MeanDO = mean(DO)), on = .(Boat, Net, time > Set, time < Lift), by = .EACHI]
#    Boat  Net                time                time MeanDO
# 1: Dawn   26 2016-05-19 12:20:11 2016-05-27 11:48:36   10.5
# 2:  Nip   26 2016-07-28 07:25:47 2016-08-07 06:13:10    9.9
# 3: Dawn 26.3 2016-08-01 13:24:51 2016-08-03 07:48:52   12.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your dodf data.frame is inputing the DO values as factors I recommend just using `data.frame`and changing the values to numeric from the get go.

```
dodf <- data.frame(time = c("2016-05-19 13:00:00", "2016-05-21 15:00:00", 
"2016-05-26 09:00:00", "2016-05-28 10:00:00", "2016-07-28 09:00:00", "2016-
07-28 19:00:00", "2016-08-04 04:00:00", "2016-08-01 05:00:00", "2016-08-02 
16:00:00", "2016-08-05 22:00:00"), 
DO = c(10.2, 10.4, 10.9, 9.4, 11.9, 12.4, 5.4, 13.2, 12.3, 2.4), 
Boat = c("Dawn", "Dawn", "Dawn", "Dawn", "Nip", "Nip", "Nip", "Dawn", "Dawn", "Dawn"), 
Net = c("26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26.3", "26.3", "26.3"))

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dodf %>% 
  left_join(catchdf, by=c('Boat', 'Net')) %>% # join the data.frames
  mutate(time=ymd_hms(time), # assign the values to a data format
         Set = ymd_hms(Set), 
         Lift = ymd_hms(Lift), y = 
           ifelse(time>=Set & time<=Lift,'in', 'out')) %>% # create a "test column"
  filter(y=='in') %>% # filter out values outside of the sample periods
  group_by(Boat, Net) %>% 
  summarise(meanDO = mean(DO))
```